# convert columns into rows in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, awk

I have one file which contain name of  mysql tables and its column names. I want to convert into following format

file: example.txt

```
Table Name        | Column Name
   ABC            |    123
   ABC            |    345
   XYZ            |    111
   FFF            |    222
   FFF            |    333
   FFF            |   4444
```

Output should be

```
ABC(123,345)
XYZ(111)
FFF(222,333,4444)
```

Please suggest me some example.

Comment: What did you try so far? Note it is not the complicated to find related answers in this site, did you check any?

Comment: I didn't find any useful can you please suggest me

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat t.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="[ \t|]+" }
NR>1 { a[$1]=a[$1]$2"," }
END {
    for (i in a)
        printf "%s(%s)\n", i, substr(a[i], 0, length(a[i])-1)
}
```

---

```
$ ./t.awk example.txt
ABC(123,345)
XYZ(111)
FFF(222,333,4444)
```

Answer (score 2):

Some like this:

```
awk -F"[ \t|]+" 'NR>2 {printf f==$1?"":")\n"} NR>1{printf (f==$1?","$2:$1"("$2)} {f=$1} END {print ")"}' file
ABC(123,345)
XYZ(111)
FFF(222,333,4444)
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but it assumes that all occurrences of the key in the first column appear contiguously.  It is not clear that this is a valid assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash (4.0+):

```
declare -A name                     # associative array

while read  a b c; do
   name[$a]="${name[$a]},$c" 
done < <( tail -n+2 "$infile" )     # skip first line

for nm in ${!name[@]}; do
  echo "$nm(${name[$nm]#,})"        # remove leading comma
done
```

The parameter substitution removes the leading comma